# convert a list of datatable to json

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, datatable, vb.net-2010

I have this function in ASP.NET to convert a `DataTable` to JSON string:

```
Public Function GetJson(ByVal dt As DataTable) As String
    Dim serializer As System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))
    Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    Try
        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
            For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr(col))
            Next
            rows.Add(row)
        Next
        Return serializer.Serialize(rows)
    Catch ex As Exception
        logFile("SP GetJson ----" + ex.Message)
        Return "-1"
    End Try
End Function
```

my json would be like that:

```
 {
"category": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "desc": "default",
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "desc": "fun",
    }
],
"images": [
    {
        "image ID": "1",
        "link": "images/logo.jpg"
        "category": "1"
    },
    {
        "image ID": "2",
        "link": "images/logo2.jpg"
        "category": "2"
    }
]
}
```

but now I have a list of 2 `DataTable`s that I need to convert it to one JSON string that has 2 arrays, any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried merging the `DataTable`s into one and then calling your convert from `DataTable` to JSON logic?

Comment: @KarlAnderson well actually if i merge the 2 `datatable`s into 1 `datatable` i will have just one array in the json string.. but in fact i need to have 2 arrays in the json string with 2 root tags..

Comment: @KarlAnderson in other words i have 2 datatables and i need to convert them in one json string but i need each datatable in json array in the same string

Comment: Would you add a short sample of JSON string you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @IvanH I edited my question and i added the json format that i need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure you are looking for is a Dictionary of Lists that are created now.
Try to deserialize your structure (the json string is corrected)

```
Dim serializer As New Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim target As String = "{'category':[{'id':'1','desc':'default'},{'id':'2','desc':'fun'}],'images':[{'imageID':'1','link':'images/logo.jpg','category':'1'},{'imageID':'2','link':'images/logo2.jpg','category':'2'}]}"
Dim Desired = serializer.Deserialize(Of Object)(target)
```

`Desired` is now the structure I need to create to get required JSON string. Now I create tables (They are in a DataSet and have names present in JSON)

```
Dim Ds As New DataSet
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, Object) In Desired
    Dim tbl As New DataTable(kvp.Key)
    Ds.Tables.Add(tbl)
    For Each drow As Dictionary(Of String, Object) In kvp.Value
        If tbl.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            For Each Name As String In drow.Keys
                tbl.Columns.Add(Name, GetType(Object))
            Next
        End If
        Dim tblRow As DataRow = tbl.NewRow
        For Each fld As KeyValuePair(Of String, Object) In drow
            tblRow(fld.Key) = fld.Value
        Next
        tbl.Rows.Add(tblRow)
    Next
Next
```

So far it I was just preparing data. Following is the desired answer.

Now I create the structure and serialize it.

```
Dim Result As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
For Each tbl As DataTable In Ds.Tables
    Result.Add(tbl.TableName, GetRows(tbl))
Next

Dim serialized As String = serializer.Serialize(Result)
```

`GetRows` is modified from `GetJson`

```
Public Function GetRows(ByVal dt As DataTable) As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))
    Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))
    Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr(col))
        Next
        rows.Add(row)
    Next
    Return rows
End Function
```

Comment: same error as the other answer .. `An item with the same key has already been added.`

Comment: I have created complete example.

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim serializer As System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))
    GetJson(dt1, rows)
    GetJson(dt2, rows)
    Dim str As String = serializer.Serialize(rows)

End Sub

Public Sub GetJson(ByVal dt As DataTable, ByRef rows As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object)))

    Try
        Dim row As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr(col))
            Next
            rows.Add(row)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        logFile("SP GetJson ----" + ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: i got an error ... `an item with the same key has been added`

Comment: I edited my question and i added the json format that i need kindly check it